# jQuery & Bootstrap - Replacing a set of classes with button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on making a web-based storyboard for video that is build on twitter bootstrap.  It consists of a container with 12 images (4 across 3 down) and a chunk of text below each image (for different sections of the video's script).

To populate the script into the boxes, I am using jquery's .text method, and the images are static links.  Because the storyboard will generally have more than 12 frames, but I only want to show that many on-screen at a time, I added a button at the bottom of the page to link to the next page.  I was planning to have that button hide the first 12 frames, and replace them with a new set. However, I can't seem to make it work.

I added the .set01 class to all of the first 12 frames, and the next button hides .set01

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
     <img src="frames/1.png" class="img-responsive" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
     <img src="frames/2.png" class="img-responsive" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
     <img src="frames/3.png" class="img-responsive" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
     <img src="frames/4.png" class="img-responsive" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
     <div class="scriptbox set01 frame01">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <div class="scriptbox set01 frame02">sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
     <div class="scriptbox set01 frame03"> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
     <div class="scriptbox set01 frame04">nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</div>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-large nextButton" value="Next Page"/>
```

JS

```
var populate1 = function(){
  $(".frame01").text("it worked!");
  $(".frame02").text("it worked!");
  $(".frame03").text("it worked!");
  $(".frame04").text("it worked!");
  }
$(document).ready(populate1);

$("nextButton").click(function{
$(".set01").hide();
});
```

The populate1 function works fine, but when I add in the button's function it breaks it, even if I don't click on the button.  I'm stumped!

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous things that can be done, starting with wrapping everything in the document.ready statement. But to simply resolve your concerns, you did not include the "period" before "nextButton" in your click event - for the button. However, your event was being triggered because you left out the open and close parens between function and { in that same statement. Should be:

```
var populate1 = function(){
    $(".frame01").text("it worked!");
    $(".frame02").text("it worked!");
    $(".frame03").text("it worked!");
    $(".frame04").text("it worked!");
}

$(document).ready(populate1);

$(".nextButton").click(function(){
    $(".set01").hide();
});
```

Comment: heh, you answered it while I was playing around with making the populate1 function and object and I got carried away, I came back and posted my original answer only to find 15mins had passed :D

Answer (score 0):

The code is wrong on the click event. You forgot the parentheses after function, also I would put that inside the document.ready event (to prevent messing with the DOM until it's, well, ready)

```
var populate1 = function(){
  $(".frame01").text("it worked!");
  $(".frame02").text("it worked!");
  $(".frame03").text("it worked!");
  $(".frame04").text("it worked!");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    populate1();
    $(".nextButton").click(function() {
        $(".set01").hide();
    });
});
```

Finally I would advise making 'frame01' etc into id's and not classes.  Id's are meant to be unique and the way you are using them makes them unique also I would remove the leading "0", just in case you need to iterate over them in future